# Assign Hotkey and Mouse Event to Logtiech Gaming Mouse

Tags: macros, gaming, logitech-mouse

I have the Logitech G602 gaming mouse. Specifically, I'm trying to set a macro where the "D" key is pressed, followed by a right-click under the cursor.

Even in the advanced settings, I couldn't find a menu where I could access both events. Also, the multi-hotkey recording function *does not* record mouse clicks...

I also noticed there were possible options for scripting, and maybe using [Logitech's SDKs](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-sg/developers)? Is this the correct direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found it. Didn't Google hard enough.

You right-click between the recorded keystroke events in that respective option, and you can choose to insert a mouse event there, including right-click.